# Flutter Google SignIn Method Not Navigate Other Page

Tags: flutter, google-signin

My app contains Google Sign. I can auth successfully. And I want auth is success navigate to Bottom Nav Bar Page. But method not return bottom nav bar. Only i click back button i can show bottom nav bar.

```html
class CheckIsLogged extends StatelessWidget {
  const CheckIsLogged({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => GoogleSignInProvider(),
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              final provider = Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context);
              if (provider.isSigningIn) {
                return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: primaryColor));
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return const BottomNavigationBarPage();
              } else {
                return const FirstPage();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

```html
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'appTitle',
      home: const CheckIsLogged(),
      // home: const RegisterPage(),
    );
  }
```

And my provider here. Actually everything is okey. But I want just navigate after auth. When i put print after auth i can see it my console.

```html
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:question_app/main.dart';
import 'package:question_app/services/database_service.dart';

String? userId;
var userAlready = '';
int correctCount = 0;
int wrongCount = 0;

class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  bool? _isSigningIn;

  GoogleSignInProvider() {
    _isSigningIn = false;
  }

  bool get isSigningIn => _isSigningIn!;

  set isSigningIn(bool isSigningIn) {
    _isSigningIn = isSigningIn;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future login() async {
    isSigningIn = true;

    final user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (user == null) {
      isSigningIn = false;
      return;
    } else {
      final googleAuth = await user.authentication;
      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

      isSigningIn = false;

      var db = Mysql();
      db.getConnection().then((conn) {
        uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email;
        debugPrint('User ID: $uid');
        debugPrint('User UID: $uid');
        String sql = 'select uid from users where uid = "$uid"';
        conn.query(sql).then((results) {
          for (var row in results) {
            userAlready = row[0].toString();
          }
          if (userAlready == uid) {
            debugPrint('Is not empty...');
            debugPrint('User Already Saved :' + userAlready);
          } else {
            debugPrint('Is empty...');
            debugPrint('User Saving :' + uid!);
            String sql = 'insert into users (uid) values ("$uid")';
            conn.query(sql).then((results) {});
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }

  void logout() async {
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to navigate to another page when your future loads suffuly you have to

```
class CheckIsLogged extends StatelessWidget {
  const CheckIsLogged({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => GoogleSignInProvider(),
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              final provider = Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context);
              if (provider.isSigningIn) {
                return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: primaryColor));
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return const BottomNavigationBarPage();
              } else {
              Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const FirstPage()),
  );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: Thats not working. Sorry

Comment: I also added my Provider code